# How to group models in django admin?

Tags: python, django

Lets say I have a group of models that must be kept separate (visually) in the admin from another group.

Right now they are alphabetic, which jumbles them.

I'd like to organize them this way:

---

### Group 1:  (custom named)

- Model 1
- Model 4

### Group 2 (custom named)

- Model 2
- Model 3

---

I cannot seem to find the documentation on how to do this. Is this even possible?

Comment: I think the easiest way is to create two different apps Group1 and Group2.

Answer (score -6, accepted):

You need to create two apps. first app == Group 1. second app == Group 2.

Then, you need to create [proxy model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#proxy-models) in your new app. Something like this.

```
class ProxyReview(Review):
    class Meta:
        proxy = True    
        # If you're define ProxyReview inside review/models.py,
        #  its app_label is set to 'review' automatically.
        # Or else comment out following line to specify it explicitly               
        # app_label = 'review'

        # set following lines to display ProxyReview as Review
        # verbose_name = Review._meta.verbose_name
        # verbose_name_plural = Review._meta.verbose_name_plural


# in admin.py
admin.site.register(ProxyReview)
```

Comment: Splitting the an app in two is overkill for adjusting display on the admin page.

Comment: _Sometimes_ this is the most elegant solution! I use django-modeladmin-reorder a LOT, but it definitely has its drawbacks.

Answer (score 32):

I do not think that splitting up your business logic, i.e. your app, when all you want to achieve is some kind of markup is the right way. Instead I found the Python package [django-modeladmin-reorder](https://github.com/mishbahr/django-modeladmin-reorder) that lets you achieve this easily. You can combine its feature of labelling apps and reordering models to group models of one app in the admin. After following the installation instructions, add something like this to your `settings.py`

```
ADMIN_REORDER = (
    # First group
    {'app': 'myapp', 'label': 'Group1',
     'models': ('myapp.Model_1',
                'myapp.Model_4',)
    },
    # Second group: same app, but different label
    {'app': 'myapp', 'label': 'Group2',
     'models': ('myapp.Model_2',
     'myapp.Model_3',)
    },)
```

Comment: this package doesn't look like it is supported since years.. anyone tried it?

Comment: Yes, it works for django 2.0. I'm using django 2.0.3. Note the app name is the name which was defined in class XxxConfig(AppConfig) at your apps.py.

Comment: I am not a big fan of installing packages that are not essential. Why not encoding enumeration in verbose_name_plural in every model? E.g. 

class Model_1(..):

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "93 Config: Office Names"

Comment: @VengaVenga because that is a hack. And it is also nice to be able to put the group header in place with a nice label, for separation.

Answer (score -1):

Please make sure that your model names in **ADMIN_REORDER** have to be **exact** as written in your models.py file.

For me, it worked with Django==3.1.5 without any issue. Here is my sample code in the settings.py file

```
ADMIN_REORDER = (
# 'webapp',

#### First group
{
    'app': 'webapp', 
    'label': 'group1',
    'models': (
        'webapp.ProductModelName_1', 
        'webapp.ProductModelName_2', 
        'webapp.ProductModelName_3',

    )
},
# Second group: same app, but different label
{
    'app': 'webapp', 
    'label': 'group2',
    'models': (
        'webapp.Model_X', 
        'webapp.Model_Y',
    )
},
)
```